# Convexity/Concavity of Thermodynamic Potentials and Entropy Maximization

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

In a brief review of thermodynamics, our lecture notes read

> Thermodynamic potentials are concave in their extensive variables and
>   convex in their intensive variables.

Alright, we start with $U(S,V)$, with both its proper variables being extensive. Now all other thermodynamic potentials that we can derive by means of the Legendre transform are intensive in the new, intensive variables. By the properties of the transform, the transformed function is concave in the new variable, if it was convex in the old variable, and vice-versa.

But can I show that $S(U,V)$ is **concave** in its proper variables, and $U(S,V)$ is **convex** in its proper variables and that $S$ is maximal for the system in equilibrium with only the formulation of the 2$^{\text{nd}}$ Law of Thermodynamics

> In an isolated system ($\delta Q=0$), the entropy can only increase.

or do I need an additional "though experiment" or postulate for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An equilibrium system at constant $U$ and $V$ has a  well defined and constant value of entropy. The only possibility of increasing that value is as a consequence of modifying some internal constraint (removing walls, making them permeable to heat, etc.). However, the fully unconstrained system at fixed $U$ and $V$ (if it is a thermodynamic system) should have a finite value of the entropy. Therefore the equilibrium condition after constraint removal is the maximum value compatible with the new conditions.

The concavity of $S(U,V)$ can be obtained immediately if extensiveness is taken for granted.

Let's consider a system, internally constrained by fixed adiabatic walls, made by two subsystems of the same substance,  with energy $\tilde U_1$ and volume $\tilde V_1$, and $\tilde U_2$ and $\tilde V_2$ respectively.
The additivity of entropy implies that the entropy of the constrained system is
$$
S(\tilde U_1,\tilde V_1)+S(\tilde U_2,\tilde V_2)
$$
If we remove the walls, we expect to get an equilibrium system of the same substance at the energy $\tilde U_1+\tilde U_2$ and at volume $\tilde V_1+\tilde V_2$. The entropy of such a system is
$$
S(\tilde U_1+\tilde U_2,\tilde V_1+\tilde V_2)\geq S(\tilde U_1,\tilde V_1)+S(\tilde U_2,\tilde V_2) \tag{1}
$$
where the  $\geq$ relation follows from the maximum of entropy principle; the possibility of equality is required to allow for phase coexistence.
Now, for any choice of $U_1$ and $U_2 = U-U_1$, and  $V_1$ and $V_2 = V-V_1$, and for any $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$, we can define  $\tilde U_1 = \lambda U_1$, $\tilde V_1 = \lambda V_1$, $\tilde U_2 = (1-\lambda) U_2$ and $\tilde V_2 = (1-\lambda) V_2$. Therefore, by using the extensiveness ($S(\lambda U, \lambda V) = \lambda S(U,V)$) in the inequality ($1$), we get the condition of  concavity of the entropy:
$$
S(\lambda U_1+(1-\lambda) U_2,\lambda V_1+(1-\lambda)  V_2)\geq \lambda S(U_1, V_1)+(1-\lambda) S(U_2,V_2), \tag{2}
$$
for every $U_1$, $U_2$, $V_1$, $V_2$, and $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$. In a similar way for convexity of $U(S,V)$

Comment: But couldn't you use here instead of $\lambda$ and $(1-\lambda)$ something like $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ without enforcing $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 =1$?

Comment: @TobiasFünke The condition $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$ is essential to the definition of convexity/concavity.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but my question was that you don't need this constraint for the derivation, no? Put differently, doesn't the derivation quite generally yields $S(\lambda_1 U_1 + \lambda_2 U_2, \lambda_1 V_1 +\lambda_2 V_2)\geq \lambda_1 S(U_1,V_2) + \lambda_2 S(U_2,V_2)$ for all $ \lambda_1,\lambda_2\geq 0$? (Which in particular holds for $\lambda_2 =1-\lambda_1$)

Comment: @TobiasFünke Yes, of course. But for proof of concavity soon or later, we have to introduce the condition of the sum equal to $1$.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Now I have modified the proof in such a way that it is clear that we fix $U_1,V_1,U,V$ and, for every $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$, the concavity inequality holds.

Comment: Ah, okay. I asked because the textbooks I've checked derived the concavity by showing that $S((X_1+X_2)/2) \geq 1/2 (S(X_1) + S(X_2)) $ and then argue with the continuity of the entropy function. But this really just implies concavity, I think, and not that the inequality holds for all $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\geq 0$ (which after all is a stronger statement). So I was not sure. Thanks again!

Comment: @TobiasFünke Sometimes (see, for instance, Callen's textbook), the milder condition of mid-point concavity (the inequality you have cited) is demonstrated. Mid-point concavity does not imply concavity without the additional request of continuity. However, since additivity + continuity implies extensiveness, it seems to me more natural to show the concavity the way I have done it.